# type definition for rxjs.concat

Tags: typescript, rxjs

[Rxjs concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) is used to subscribe to a group of observables in sequence.

each observable waits for the previous one to complete.

also, I use `toArray` operator to combine all emitted results into a single array.

this approach mimics `forkJoin` but subscribes to the inner observables in sequence.

the following code works fine for me, exactly as expected

```
concat(of<string>('a'), of<number>(1))
  .pipe(toArray())
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);   
  });

// logs: a, 1
```

the problem here is with type definition.

as with `forkJoin`, the result is an array of the types of the inner observables in order.

i.e `result: Array<string,number>`

but here in `concat` it is different.
`result: Array<string|number>`
specially with `strict: true` in `tsconfig.json`

the following type definition works, but not as desired

```
concat(of<string>('a'), of<number>(1))
  .pipe(toArray())
  .subscribe((result: (string | number)[]) => {
    console.log({ result });
  });
```

but the following desired type definition dosen't work

```
concat(of<string>('a'), of<number>(1))
  .pipe(toArray())
  .subscribe((result: [string, number]) => {
    console.log({ result });
  });
```

[stackblitz playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dqg3jk?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Comment: I don't think TS can't infer the type because the number of emissions from each source observable is not known until run time.

Comment: I just want to tell ts about the type, not let it infer it by itself

Comment: What do you mean: "*but the following desired type definition doesn't work*" ?

Answer (score 1):

> the problem here is with type definition.

> as with forkJoin, the result is an array of the types of the inner observables in order.

> i.e result: Array<string,number>

Please be aware that `Array<string, number>` is not a valid TS type. You probably meant to say `[string, number]`, which is a Tuple.

The thing is the types of the `toArray` operator are not trying to infer a Tuple, but an Array. Also, even if they did try to infer a Tuple, it would be impossible to infer what you want because the type of the Observable that's returned from `concat` is a union.

For instance, the type of the following observable:

```
concat(
  of('foo'),
  of(2),
  of('bar'),
  of(null),
  of(5)
)
```

is `Observable<string | number | null>`.

So, since it's impossible to infer a Tuple like `[string, number, string, null, number]` from the type `Observable<string | number | null>`. It's also impossible to write an operator that infers the types that you want.

However, if you want a super-hacky "solution" you could create your own `toTuple` operator, which would in fact have the same behavior of the original `toArray` operator, but with different (super-hacky) types. Something like this:

```
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

type ToTuple = <A extends Array<any>>() => (
  source$: Observable<any>
) => Observable<
  A extends [...infer AA] ? AA : unknown
>

const toTuple = toArray as ToTuple
```

And then you could use like this:

```
const test = concat(of('a'), of(1))
  .pipe(toTuple<[string, number]>())
  .subscribe((result) => {});
```

and then `result` would be typed as `[string, number]`.

However, I don't recommend doing this, because the types of this `toTuple` operator don't even try to make sure that the source Observable is compliant with the types that come out from `toTuple`, meaning that TS wouldn't throw any compile errors if you did something like this:

```
const test = concat(of('a'), of(null))
  .pipe(toTuple<[undefined, number]>())
  .subscribe((result) => {});
```

which IMO defeats the purpose of using TS.

Although, I'm thinking that there is possibly a way to have TS to throw a compile error if at least the source Observable is not a union of the types passed into `toTuple`, so if we "improved" the types of that `ToTuple` perhaps we would be able to have TS throw in the previous example, but then TS wouln't throw for something like this:

```
const test = concat(of(5), of(undefined))
  .pipe(toTuple<[undefined, number]>())
  .subscribe((result) => {});
```

So, yeah, even with the best types that I can think of TS wouldn't yell at you for doing something like that.